# How to combine two identical fields into one for accurate results

Tags: sql-server

I don't know how to explain this but I'll try hard. I have code that sends a friend request to another user of a site I'm developing. and there are two email fields for that which is the req_email (for the requestor) and the resp_email (for the responder). the code I currently have displays friends of the sender field alone. But sometimes the sender can also be a responder since others may send him requests.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN status = 'Yes' THEN 'Friends' 
            ELSE CASE WHEN status = 'No' THEN 'Request Sent' 
                      ELSE CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'Send Request' END 
                 END 
       END AS Answer,
       *
FROM dbo.profile p
LEFT JOIN friends f On p.email = f.[resp_email] AND f.[req_email] = MMColParam
WHERE fname LIKE %varsearch% 
      AND email NOT LIKE MMColParam2
ORDER BY fname ASC
```

Now my issue is how to combine both the sender_email and the responder email as one so the results are returned in one instance

Comment: i asked it yesterday but what i'm now is different from the answer given. this time is about merging two fields with identical variables together

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. please check following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN status = 'Yes' THEN 'Friends' 
            WHEN status = 'No' THEN 'Request Sent' 
            WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'Send Request' 
       END AS Answer,
       *
FROM dbo.profile p    
LEFT JOIN friends f On p.email = f.[resp_email] AND f.[req_email] = MMColParam
WHERE fname LIKE '%varsearch%'
  AND email NOT LIKE 'MMColParam2'
ORDER BY fname ASC
```

Comment: this only works for the req_email column but not the the resp_email. for example   there is "user1" in req_email column that has requested friendship and is being responded as by user2 in resp_mail column, now when "user2" logs on  it can't tell that users1 is a friend to user2. but it can tell when user1 logs on that user2 is your friend

Comment: @blay. Can you say sample data and sample output data.